# Initializing a static vector with static objects in Microsoft Visual C++ 2008?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2008

I have a class called Color which has some static Color objects in them.  I would like to have a static vector of these static Color objects, but I do not know how to initialize the vector because the version of C++ I am using does not support list initialization.  I have been told (to my chagrin) that I must use this older version of C++.

Here is my Color.h file:

```
#ifndef COLOR_H
#define COLOR_H

#include <vector>

class Color { 
    public:
        Color( float red, float green, float blue, float alpha = 1.0f );

        float r, g, b, a;

        static Color red;
        static Color yellow;
        static Color blue;

        static std::vector<Color> colors;
};

#endif /* COLOR_H */
```

And in Color.cpp:

```
#include "Color.h"

Color::Color( float red, float green, float blue, float alpha ) {
    r = red;
    g = green;
    b = blue;
    a = alpha;
}

Color Color::red(0.85, 0.0, 0.0);
Color Color::yellow(0.93, 0.93, 0.0);
Color Color::blue(0.0, 0.0, 0.93);

std::array<Colors> arr = {Color::red, Color::blue, Color::yellow};
```

However, this last line does not work because list initialization isn't supported.  What is the alternative?  How do I add `red`, `yellow`, and `blue` to `colors`?

Comment: Initializer list is part of C++11, which isn't supported in VS2008/VS2010. I think it is in the newest version of VS 2012, though.

Try using a std::vector and use push_back() on it.

Comment: I know that initializer list isn't supported and I cannot upgrade my version of VS.  I'm asking what the alternative to initializer list is.

Comment: Have you tried including the size? I.E. `std::array<Colors, 3> arr = {Color::red, Color::blue, Color::yellow};` I don't have VS2008 so I can't compile it myself..

Comment: I do not want to include the size because in my actual code I have many items I'm listing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can handle a bit of startup overhead, put your initialization in a function:

```
std::vector<Color> init_colors() {
    Color arr[] = {Color::red, Color::blue, Color::yellow};
    return std::vector<color>(arr, arr + sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]));
}

std::vector<Color> colors = init_colors();
```